# how to chain method

Tags: php

I'm using https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm and query DB like this:

```
$result = ORM::for_table('users')->join('messages', array('users.uid', '=', 'messages.uid'))->where('mid', '5')->find_many();
```

and now i wanna to add a condition:

```
$result = ORM::for_table('users')->join('messages', array('users.uid', '=', 'messages.uid'));
if(true) {
  $result->where('mid', '5');
}
$result->find_many();
```

However it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on air4x's comment:

The interface to these methods is considered ["fluent" or "fluid"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) because they return themselves (so the `join()` function returns the ORM object with the join embedded in it, instead of say, returning `true` or `false`)

```
$result->where('mid, '5');
```

..will set the `where` but then the object is discarded.

```
$result = $result->where('mid', '5');
```

..will save the modified object.